# Fast way to convert BufferedImage to byte array, and add alpha

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm using the following to add overlay to a video; but it doesn't perform well because it requires to process every pixels (which is A LOT of work if you have full-HD at 50 frames/sec!)

```
private static byte[] convert(BufferedImage image, int opacity)
{
    int imgWidth  = image.getWidth();
    int imgHeight = image.getHeight();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[imgWidth * imgHeight * 4]

    int imgLoc = 0;

    for(int y=0; y < imgHeight; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x  < imgWidth; x++)
        {
            int argb = image.getRGB(x, y);

            imgBuffer[(imgLoc*4)+0] = (byte)((argb>>0)&0x0FF);
            imgBuffer[(imgLoc*4)+1] = (byte)((argb>>8)&0x0FF);
            imgBuffer[(imgLoc*4)+2] = (byte)((argb>>16)&0x0FF);

            int alpha = ((argb>>24)&0x0FF);
            if (opacity < 100)
                alpha = (alpha*opacity)/100;

            imgBuffer[(imgLoc*4)+3] = (byte)alpha;

            imgLoc++;
        }
    }
```

How can I re-write this code to perform better? I've tried many different things, e.g.:

- image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null, 0, image.getWidth());
- ((DataBufferByte) image.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData()

But none of these seem to work; the overlay doesn't show up, while the slower method at least shows the overlay.

*PS: I know the ARGB is converted to ABGR in the function above; I'll fix that later. The overlay should still show, albeit in different colors*